# mongodb linq provider: incorrect behavior for fields of type decimal?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

Using mongodb version 3.4.3, c# driver (nuget MongoDb.Driver) version 2.4.3

Given a class with a field `Amount` of type `decimal`, and a mongodb collection of this type. Querying the collection for entries with amounts bigger or smaller than a certain value gives incorrect results. When changing the type to 'int', then the code behaves correctly. Is there some issue when using decimal fields in MongoDb?

The sample code below illustrates the issue.

```
class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

// assumes a locally installed mongodb 
var connectionstring = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
var mongo = new MongoClient(connectionstring);
var db = mongo.GetDatabase("test");

db.DropCollection("testcollection");
db.CreateCollection("testcollection");
var collection = db.GetCollection<C>("testcollection");

// populate with 2 instances (amount 1 and amount 10)

collection.InsertMany(new[]
{
    new C{Id = 1, Description = "small", Amount = 1},
    new C{Id = 2, Description = "large", Amount = 10},
});

// verify that the documents are indeed persisted as expected
var all = collection.AsQueryable().ToList();
Debug.Assert(all.Count == 2);
Debug.Assert(all[1].Amount == 10);

// the assert below inexplicably fails (the query returns no results)
var largerThan5 = collection.AsQueryable().Where(c => c.Amount > 5).ToList();
Debug.Assert(largerThan5.Count == 1);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]` to the `Amount` field ?

Comment: @Veeram I tried and it fails when trying to insert.

Comment: @Evk I can`t test it against 3.4 server. I know it fails with the error that you have mentioned in your post in 3.2 which is expected. I was expecting it to work on 3.4 though.

Comment: @Veeram, you are right. I did test against 3.4, but what I missed is that BSON decimal requires setting `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion`, and without that it still fails with the same error as in 3.2. With that setting however it works as expected, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because it will convert all your decimals to strings (so they will store in string column in mongo database). Of course your `gt` comparisions will fail in this case. There is a very old issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-196) about that, which is closed as "works as intended". As far as I know - at those times there were no decimal BSON type, so that behavior was reasonable.

Now [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/#numeric-decimal) you can see that there is new decimal BSON type in version 3.4, and actually C# driver already has support for it. However, if you will just use .NET `decimal` type - it will still convert it to string, even with mongo 3.4.

What you need to do (since you are running 3.4) is:

1. Decorate your `Amount` with `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]`:

   ```
   class C
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]
       public decimal Amount { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Set feature compatibility version to 3.4, because BSON decimal cannot be handled by previous versions as stated [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/#backwards-incompatible-features):

   ```
   db.adminCommand({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4"})
   ```

After that, your decimal will be correctly mapped and query will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but wow. Just wow. This is extremely unintuitive from a C# / .Net perspective... And just plain wrong, if you ask me. I'd say the driver should throw an exception rather than silently allowing the query but returning wrong results.

Comment: Yes I agree, though I'd say it should not allow to map decimals at all, prior to 3.4 at least, because silently map them to strings is not very good behavior either.